# API Key with colon, parsing it gives TypeError: forEach isn't a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, url

I'm trying to use New York Times API in order to get the Top Stories in `JSON` but I keep on getting a:

***Uncaught TypeError: top.forEach is not a function***

I feel like there's something wrong with the API key since it has `:` colons in the url. I even tried to encode it with `%3A` but it still doesn't work.

This is the basic url:

http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key={API-KEY}

My function that grabs the data from the url:
```

```
function topStories(topStoriesURL) {
    $.getJSON(topStoriesURL, function(top) {
        top.forEach(function(data) {
            link = data.results.url;
                cardTitle = data.results.title;
                if(data.results.byline == "") { postedBy = data.results.source; }
                else { postedBy = data.results.byline; }
                imgSource = data.results.media[0].media-metadata[10].url;
                createCardElements();
        });
    });
}
```

I `console.log(url)` and when I click it inside Chrome console, it ignored the part of the key that comes after the colon. I've been debugging, but I can't seem to figure out the error.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood, but the error is with the `top` object, which occurs before the `url` is even created. so what leads you to believe that the url is the problem??

Comment: the colon may be a specific port you're supposed to use.

Comment: Because we can't access that URL without an API key, can you post a sample of the JSON response that you get (omit any sensitive data) - it is almost certainly not an array at the top level.

Comment: @GregL http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=sample-key

Comment: @Pamblam I tried the `url` without encoding the colon in url and when I console.log(url), it ignored everything after the colon, leaving me with a 403 error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version of the code that works.

```
function topStories(topStoriesURL) {
  $.getJSON(topStoriesURL, function(data) {
    if (data.error) {
      alert('error!'); // TODO: Add better error handling here
    } else {
      data.results.forEach(function(result) {
        var link = result.url,
          cardTitle = result.title,
          postedBy = result.byline == "" ? result.source : result.byline,
          hasMultimedia = (result.multimedia || []).length > 0,
          imgSource = hasMultimedia ? result.multimedia[result.multimedia.length - 1].url : null;
        createCardElement(link, cardTitle, postedBy, imgSource);
      });
    }
  });
}

function createCardElement(link, title, postedBy, imgSource) {
  // create a single card element here
  console.log('Creating a card with arguments of ', arguments);
}

topStories('http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=sample-key');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely going to need to do a for ... in loop on the top object since it is an object.  You can not do a forEach upon on object the syntax would probably look like this:

```
function topStories(topStoriesURL) {
  $.getJSON(topStoriesURL, function(top) {
      for (var datum in top) {
          link = datum.results.url;
              cardTitle = datum.results.title;
              if(datum.results.byline == "") { postedBy = datum.results.source; }
              else { postedBy = datum.results.byline; }
              imgSource = datum.results.media[0].media-metadata[10].url;
              createCardElements();
      });
  });
}
```

[Heres the documentation on for...in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: I tried doing a `for (var data in top)` but then I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined"